# How to store database name in entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to create a read-only property `[NotMapped]Database {get;}` on a POCO entity class to reflect the name of the database from which the entity was loaded at the time of creation so that I can read the value later when no `DbContext` instance is available.  How do I tell EF to load this data at object creation time?

I know about `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`, but that is not what I want to do.  I want to set the property to the current database name when the object is being instantiated via a `DbContext` class.

I have searched for this problem but haven't been able to find any information to provide here, perhaps I don't know how to phrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. First create some interface:

```
public interface IHasDatabaseName {
    string Database { set; }
}
```

And implement for entity in question. Then in constructor of your `DbContext` (or at any place where you construct your `DbContext`, if you use DI container for example), subscribe to `ObjectMaterialized` event:

```
// this is DbContext here
((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += ObjectContextOnObjectMaterialized;
```

And then:

```
// this is DbContext here
private void ObjectContextOnObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs objectMaterializedEventArgs) {
    var dbName = objectMaterializedEventArgs.Entity as IHasDatabaseName;
    if (dbName != null) {
        dbName.Database = this.Database.Connection.Database;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a computed column on the table to fetch that information.  Something like:

```
alter table YourTable add [Database] AS DB_NAME();
```

Then define your POCO property as `Database {get;}`.

Comment: I can't modify the storage layer and because I want this value on every class, that would be too large an undertaking.